# If select Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou com uma duvida aqui e gostaria de uma ajuda.
 tenho um controller onde tem que fazer uma consulta na tabela de Caixas onde verifica se o caixa esta aberto ou fechado.

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {   
        $caixas = DB::select('SELECT * FROM caixas INNER JOIN
        users ON users.id = users.id JOIN caixas c ON c.data_abertura = c.data_abertura');

        if( $caixas )
            return view('vendas.index', compact('caixas'));
        else
            return view('vendas.caixa');
    }
```

Ele ta funcionando, porem quando eu logo com user 1 e abro o caixa ele abre e faz o `if` blz, se eu deslogar e logar com o user 2 ele continua com o caixa aberto, não identifica que o user 2 esta com caixa fechado.

Obrigado.

Comment: Esse `on` do select não tem sentido. E onde você usa a informação do user nessa query ? E porque não usa o Eloquent para obter a informação do banco?

Comment: Olá Isac, estou tentando fazer que quando logar no sistema no menu PDV ele verifique se o caixa esta aberto ou fechado assim entrando no if porem não estou conseguindo validar isso, pois quando abro o caixa com user 1 blz, ai se deslogo e logo com user 2 verifica que o user 2 esta com caixa fechado, teria um exemplo disso com o eloquent? Obrigado

Comment: Para usar Eloquent e obter a mesma informação tem de ter os modelos e relações construídos corretamente. Onde você usa a informação do user que está logado ? Não vejo isso nessa query. E como deteta se tem a caixa aberta ou fechada ?

Comment: Na verdade não sei se o user logado vai resolver, mais o que eu preciso que o sistema faça, seria uma validação que quando o user1 logar no sistema para operar o caixa ele identifique se o caixa esta aberto ou não ai teria uma consulta na tabela status por exemplo, e no caso de haver mais caixas tipo supermercado ele identifique que o usuario logado estaria com caixa aberto ou não. me desculpe se não estou conseguindo explicar direito, obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Você está verificando o retorno do consulta, ou seja, se a consulta retorna um resultado sempre será true, por que o php efetua esta [conversão antes de verificar](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.boolean.php) no if.

Também observei que o INNER JOIN que você está fazendo parece meio estranho na cláusula ON "users.id = users.id". Um JOIN é feito para consultar resultados com colunas relacionadas.

Ex: `SELECT * FROM caixa INNER JOIN user ON user.id = caixa.user_id;`

> obs: não sei se no seu banco está assim, é só um exemplo.

Espero que tenha te ajudado.

Comment: As colunas estão relacionadas, Com esse select, deu certo. obrigado, Abraço

Answer (score 0):

Caso use model tem um jeito mais prático de fazer isso:

```
//Caixas seria o Model

Caixas::with('user')->where('data_abertura', $data_abertura)->get();
```

Com Query builder ficaria simples também

```
DB::table('caixas')->join('users', 'caixas.user_id','=', 'users.id')->where('data_abertura', $data_abertura)->get();
```